# Missing config features on Opendayligth Rest API

Tags: opendaylight

I am using the YangUI on the REST API of ODL(Oxygen Release) and I want to use the config features of opendaylight-inventory but I can only see the operational ones. Like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ayUdA.png).

¿What can be the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved installing the same features on a previous ODL release. I don't know why but I can't see config features on Oxygen.